# formArray looping incomplete values

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hi i have a form which has dynamic fields of amount for which i am using formArray. The user can generate multiple fields of amount.

What i want is to calculate the total values in all dynamic fields and show error message if total amount is exceeded.

The problem is when i loop over formArray in the customer validator function, It doesnt prints out complete values. Below is the stackblitz. You can see in the console. When you type some number it is not getting printed completely.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sbidt3

Answer (score 1):

How are you doing.

It was kind of difficult to follow your code, but I think I found the root of your problem. **You are using a getter function to loop in an ngFor**. You shouldn´t.

Getter functions are re-evaluated in every change detection, that means the array is recreated, this is why the value you are seeing on the console is the previous one.

I really encourage you to follow a guided example (like this one https://medium.com/aubergine-solutions/add-push-and-remove-form-fields-dynamically-to-formarray-with-reactive-forms-in-angular-acf61b4a2afe) to add dynamic form fields.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Following up Miguel's great explanation, I think this is a way to solve this problem, although I wouldn't recommend it that much:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
        this.add_conversion_form.controls.map(res=>{
        console.log(res.value);
        let sum  = Number(res.value.amount);
        total = total + sum;
        console.log("total:"+ total);
    });
})
```

### EDIT

Actually, it might have nothing to do with change detection and all that good stuff.

So, you set a **validator** on a `FormControl` and, in that validator, you are trying to get `FormControl` instances from `FormGroup`, which is the parent of the current `FormControl`.

Also, notice that a `FormControl` has a `_pending` value, which kind of makes me think that a value from a `FormControl` is **not immediately transmitted** to its `FormGroup` parent.

So, I think that's why you can't get the updated value right in the `FormControl`.

But, if you set a `validator` for the `FormGroup`, you could see the updated values, which makes sense to me.

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input formControlName="name" type="text" />
</form>
```

```js
/* ... */

ngOnInit () {
 this.form = this.fb.group({
    name: this.fb.control('', this.customVal.bind(this))
  })

  this.form.validator = (g) => {
    // Here you should have the updated value
    console.log('f group validator', g)
  }
}

public customVal (c: FormControl) {
   // The current control's value is not reflected in the parent FormGroup from here
   console.log(this.form)

   console.log(c.value)

  return null;
}

/* ... */
```

Comment: cant see how it helps my case.Can you add a stackblitz with my case!

Comment: Your StackBlitz example is currently broken. You are attaching a `FormArray` validator to a `FormControl` and you're getting an error. Please have a closer look.

Comment: i dont see how its broken. Kindly provide a solved stackblitz or use mine instead for explanation